# How to be undetectable with chrome webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've already seen multiple posts on Stackoverflow regarding this. However, some of the answers are outdated (such as using PhantomJS) and others didn't work for me.

I'm using selenium to scrape a few sports websites for their data.  However, every time I try to scrape these sites, a few of them block me because they know I'm using chromedriver.  I'm not sending very many requests at all, and I'm also using a VPN.  I know the issue is with chromedriver because anytime I stop running my code but try opening these sites on chromedriver, I'm still blocked.  However, when I open them in my default web browser, I can access them perfectly fine.

So, I wanted to know if anyone has any suggestions of how to avoid getting blocked from these sites when scraping them in selenium.  I've already tried changing the '$cdc...' variable within the chromedriver, but that didn't work.  I would greatly appreciate any ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously they can tell you're not using a common browser. Could it have something to do with the User Agent?

Try it out with something like Postman. See what the responses are. Try messing with the user agent and other request fields. Look at the request headers when you access the site with a regular browser (like chrome) and try to spoof those.

Edit: just remembered this and realized the page might be performing some checks in JS and whatnot. It's worth looking into what happens when you block JS on the site with a regular browser.

Comment: I'll look into those things.  Thank you so much!